# Why formik is losing focus immediatelly I hit the second field?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a form with `formik` that is losing focus at the second field.

It's seems to be a really basic stuff, but I can't find the problem.

Check this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-forked-m145g

Click on the e-mail field, type anything (or nothing), hit tab to jump to the next field and watch the focus going away.

As you can see, the field is beeing validated, so, I don't know (and would find quite unlikely) if my custom `handleBlur` function had something to do with it:

```
const customHandleBlur = (e) => {
  if (!values.recaptcha) this._reCaptchaRef.current.execute();
  handleBlur(e);
};
```

This function is responsible to execute Google's recaptcha v3.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your customHandleBlur to only execute if you have a value for both email and description.

```
  const customHandleBlur = (e) => {
     if (!!values.email && !!values.description && !values.recaptcha) this._reCaptchaRef.current.execute();
    handleBlur(e);
  };
```

This will keep the description from losing focus when the this._reCaptchaRef.current.execute() function is called.

It looks like there are other issues to... but this will keep your description field from losing the focus, which is what your question was.

Comment: What other issues do you refer? If you could just say them it would be of great help :)

Comment: I didn't spend a lot of time testing other stuff. I was only focused on solving your question. Let me know if there is something else that doesn't work.